# How to apply a texture to the background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

I was trying to follow this tutorial to build a website and on Step 2, it said that I should paint the jpeg texture to the background.

http://www.designzzz.com/how-to-make-web-template-photoshop/

I'm new to Photoshop so I'm not sure how this is done.  Is there some specific technique to which the author is referring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**there is a very simple way to do this,in this tutorial the guy used another technique to apply pattern,we have something very easy than that**
go to the layer on which you want to apply texture/pattern.double click on it,a window will pop out saying layer style,**in tutorial he also applied a color to make blue bit dark/another color, you can do this by applying a new colored layer just above the background layer(which contains the pattern) with less opacity**.I have attached a SS to make you clear about how to apply pattern on layer in another way,don't get confused with it, it's very simple,hope this will help you....you can create your own pattern of anything,very detailed explanation given by **Farray** in another answer Please follow the same.

[image]

Comment: +1  I always forget about most of the options in Layer Styles, including Pattern overlay.

Comment: In addition, clicking on the little triangle gadget on the pattern selection palette will pop up a menu where you can load textures from files and other sources...

Answer (score 2):

1. In Photoshop, select the pixels that you want to use as your pattern.
2. In the `Edit` menu, choose `Define pattern...` and you now have a pattern.

   [image: Select and define the pattern]
3. When you select your paintbucket (`g` shortcut), you can now choose a pattern and your pattern will be selectable in the tool options.

   [image: Pattern bucket me, yo]

   [image: Fill yo pattern bucket, er, yo]

   [image: This pattern is going to make me a rich man]

Patterns are awesome because if you create "seamless" patterns, you can paint large swaths of texture in an image.  Useful for repeating backgrounds or just texturing.  To make it "seamless", the easiest way is to use `Filter -> Other -> Offset` with wrap-around edge pixels.  This will show you how the edges of your texture look when it tiles on a canvas.

Comment: very well explained +1